# Twilio reinitializing client

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm having a problem with the Twilio SDK using C#. The scenario is this:

We are using the TwilioClient API, and we initialize it first with the Production credentials. For one specific endpoint we need to use it only with DEV credentials using #if DEBUG statement. To make this, we call again the TwilioClient.Init method with the DEV credentials like this:

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSidDev, authTokenDev);
```

The problem is that when calling the endpoint, it throws an error like this:

[image: Authenticate exception]

The error doesn't give more details. We isolated the same code using the DEV credentials (and not initializing the client before) and it works, but when the TwilioClient is already initialized with different credentials it doesn't work. I also tried calling the TwilioClient.Invalidate() method but didn't worked neither. Is there any way to initialize with different credentials?

Thanks

Comment: Even if you would be able to do that, it could lead to issues when you have possible parallel processing as it globally sets up the credentials. Assume a situation where the normal credentials would be used, then you land in the only-dev-section, and after that a new request comes in which will then possibly use the only dev credentials and finishes before the first call leaves the only-dev-section. I wouldn't recommend the practice you follow. But this hints to an issue with the TwilioClient implementation. Maybe you should address this with their support.

Comment: @SebastianGrunow Thanks for replying. This will not be an issue as we are only reinitializing with DEV credentials in only one place and using #if DEBUG, it will not lead to problems because it is for local testing.

Comment: According to the [implementation here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/61bee0bb7cc20f79070183ea4c4bce006eaccb2d/src/Twilio/Twilio.cs#L26) your code should only lead to issues when you pass null values as parameters.

Comment: We are not passing any null values, we are using the same code posted here https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials#test-incoming-phone-numbers but with our credentials, and in a separated project it works but if you initialize it with other credentials before, it will not work.

Comment: I think that I found some information here https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet/usage-guide#manual-client-initialization . Will give more information later if it worked. Thanks